# Apply Mail Filters to IMAP Mail Account

Tags: email, mail-server

I have a mailbox that I can access via IMAP. Unfortunately the server does not support rules like "If mail received from x@y.com, then move the mail to subfolder XY". I could only do that locally, e.g. in Thunderbird. But I think this is the wrong way, because then you would have to configure each client individually with these rules.

Instead, I wonder how to externally apply rules on the server. I imagine running a software on a server that automatically implements the rules and synchronizes the results to the IMAP server. Basically a Thunderbird that just applies the rules, does not need a UI, and ideally runs in Docker. Is there anything like this?